# Drag and drop: copy instead of move item

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have two (Telerik) TreeView controls, let's call them tvSource and tvDest. I want to drag/drop items from tvSource to tvDest. I have this somewhat working, but am experiencing two problems:

1) What it now does is moving the item. Instead I want them to be copied (from tvSource to tvDest), leaving the item in tvSource.

2) To allow items to be dragged from the tvSource control I have to enable DragDrop. With this enabled the user can drag/drop inside the tvSource control, which is not what I want. The items may only be dragged (copied) to an other control (tvDest).

Below is my code so far:

`Private blnMouseIsDown As Boolean = False`

```
Private Sub tvSource_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles tvSource.MouseDown
    blnMouseIsDown = True
End Sub

Private Sub tvDest_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles tvDest.DragDrop
    Dim p As Point = tvDest.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    Dim hoverNode As RadTreeNode = tvDest.GetNodeAt(p.X, p.Y)
    If hoverNode Is Nothing Then
        tvDest.Nodes.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString())
        Return
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tvDest_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles tvDest.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tvSource_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles tvSource.MouseMove

    If blnMouseIsDown Then
        tvSource.DoDragDrop(tvSource.SelectedNode.Name, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If
    blnMouseIsDown = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you are fighting built-in D+D support in that control.  Use a Telerik support forum to find help.

Comment: @Hans: Forum of Telerik isn't that good. As Telerik is a much used control set I think my question will be answered quicker and better here ...

Answer (score 0):

From their support site, [Enabling Drag and Drop](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/treeview-drag-and-drop-enabling-drag-and-drop.html), it looks like if you have the property `AllowDragDrop` enabled, then it will perform the full move by default (which Hans indicated).  Try setting it to false.

For your `tvDest`, enable the `AllowDrop` property, which allows for the standard windows drag and drop functionality.

Also, I don't think it's necessary to have the `blnMouseIsDown` variable or the `MouseMove` event.  Move the DoDragDrop method to the `MouseDown` event instead.

Comment: Disabling AllowDragDrop in tvSource will also disable the ability to drag, so I have to enable it.

Comment: @JanvB You mean DoDragDrop won't work if it's false?  Seems like an odd requirement.  tvSource should have AllowDragDrop and AllowDrop disabled since you don't want to drop anything in that control.

Comment: You're right, I was put on the wrong foot because with disabling it in tvSource, the DropHint isn't working on the tvDest control and I cannot choose the place in the Tree anymore.